Data label always centered and no overlapping
I have a data:
type <- c("open", "done") 
value <- c(12889, 86383) 
share <- c(0.13, 0.87) 
data <- data.frame(type,value,share) 
rownames(data) <- c("OpenValue", "DoneValue")

And created a pie chart using ggplot:
ggplot(data, aes(x = "", y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill = type)) +
  coord_polar("y") + 
  theme_void() + 
  geom_text(aes(label= value), vjust = 1, hjust = 0.5, check_overlap = TRUE, color = "black", size = 3) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#0099f9", "lightskyblue1")) + 
   theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12, vjust = -8), 
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0), 
        legend.position = "bottom") + 
  geom_label(aes(label = paste0(round(share, 2) * 100, "% of total")), 
             position = position_stack(vjust = 0.75), size = 3)

The plot looks like:

The labels are not in the middle of each area, even if I used both hjust = 0.5 and they can overlap if both value and share in percent are in the middle of each area, even if I used check_overlap = TRUE. What's wrong here? And how can I make sure the labels and the extra "labels" are always in the middle of each area and without overlapping? I mean even if one area is much smaller than the other one.

To center the labels use position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5) for both labels. And one option to avoid the overplotting would be to align one at the top using vjust=1 and one at the bottom using vjust=0. Also note that I changed the geom_text to a geom_label too.
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = "", y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = type)) +
  coord_polar("y") +
  theme_void() +
  geom_label(aes(label = value),
    vjust = 1,
    color = "black", size = 3,
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
    label.size = 0,
    fill = NA
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#0099f9", "lightskyblue1")) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12, vjust = -8),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  ) +
  geom_label(aes(label = paste0(round(share, 2) * 100, "% of total")),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3, vjust = 0
  )


